# Upload to blob tfs 2017

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

We are trying to upload the artifact to blob storage from TFS build server. AzCopy task needs the azure subscription details, which is not available to us. We need to upload the artifacts to azure blob storage using azure blob storage connection string. Is there a way to upload files to blob storage using connection string only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you can do from PowerShell you can do from build and release.  There is a task named "PowerShell" and one named "Azure PowerShell".  If you don't have the Azure subscription details I doubt you will be able to use the "Azure PowerShell" task. However, if you have a PowerShell script you run locally that works you might be able to simply run it as part of your build with the "PowerShell" task.

Option two is have someone that knows the details to create an Azure Service Endpoint for you. They never have to share the details with you to make the connection. Once the connection is created you can use it without having to ever know the details.

Comment: So trivial , sorry i did not thought about it. I did have a powershell, which i used to copy from blob storage to another blob storage, i will reuse them. Thanks a ton.